# Syntax Error: Array of URLs (VBA)

Tags: vba, parsing

My code was working -- but now I am receiving a "Syntax Error," highlighting `URL1, URL2, URL3` etc. and I'm not sure why. I thought it might be that `urlArray` should be switched to a string, but that wasn't it. Any thoughts?

Here is my full code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub getJSON()

Dim sheetCount As Integer, urlArray As Variant
sheetCount = 1

urlArray = Array(“URL1”, "URL2", "URL3", "URL4", "URL5")

Dim MyRequest As Object: Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
Dim MyUrls: MyUrls = urlArray
Dim k As Long
Dim Json As Object

For k = LBound(MyUrls) To UBound(MyUrls)
    With MyRequest
        .Open "GET", MyUrls(k)
        .Send
        Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.ResponseText)
    Dim i As Long, p As Object
    For i = 1 To Json("prices").Count
        Set p = Json("prices")(i)
        Sheets("Sheet" & sheetCount).Cells(i, 1) = p("name")
        Sheets("Sheet" & sheetCount).Cells(i, 2) = p("cost")("fareType")
        Sheets("Sheet" & sheetCount).Cells(i, 9) = p("cost")("base")
        Sheets("Sheet" & sheetCount).Cells(i, 10) = p("cost")("perMinute")
        Next i
        End With
sheetCount = sheetCount + 1
Next
End Sub
```

The JSON code I am parsing from these URLs is in the below format:

```
{"id":1,"prices":[{"name":"expressTaxi","cost":{"base":"USD4.50","fareType":
"time_plus_distance","cancelFee":"USD10.00","minimumAmt":"USD8.00","perMinute":"USD1.50",
"perDistanceUnit":"USD3.00"}}]
```

Comment: change all `“` into `"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using ” instead of " on your first index in your array URL1, just replace those and you'll be good!

So like this:

```
urlArray = Array("URL1", "URL2", "URL3", "URL4", "URL5")
```

Instead of:

```
urlArray = Array(“URL1”, "URL2", "URL3", "URL4", "URL5")
```

Comment: It's such a pain to copy a code snippet only yo find out that it has Smart Quotes ( “” ) and Backticks ( ` aka Grave accent)  in it.